# Symfony - Doctrine not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: class, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have got an inherited website. Throwing a critical error in prod mode.

```
[2017-02-28 13:11:17] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: "Class "TheZoo\Website\FrameworkBundle\Entity\Menu" is not a valid entity or mapped super class." at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php line 216 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\MappingException: Class \"TheZoo\\Website\\FrameworkBundle\\Entity\\Menu\" is not a valid entity or mapped super class. at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:216)"} []
[2017-02-28 13:11:17] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

I am not a Symfony developer but it looks like it could be down to the location of the class. "TheZoo\Website\" was part of the path on the old site.

The site works fine in debug mode. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: If the site works fine in debug mode, I would suggest to clear cache in first place.

Comment: try executing the command `doctrine:mapping:info` (tells you all of the entities that Doctrine is aware of and whether or not there are any basic errors with the mapping). More info available [here in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/console.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add the @entity annotation or if you have already the database, you can generate classes.This link can help you:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html